# How can I add a parameter on module at startup?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, lubuntu, startup

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 with an USB wifi adapter (rtl8192) and it use module `rtl8192cu.ko`

I had a problem of dropping connection now and then .

I fix my problem using these parameters :

```
rtw_power_mgnt=2 rtw_ips_mode=1 rtw_hwpwrp_detect=1 rtw_enusbss=1
```

But now every time I boot I need to:

```
sudo rmmod rtl8192cu.ko
sudo insmod rtl8192cu.ko rtw_power_mgnt=2 rtw_ips_mode=1 rtw_hwpwrp_detect=1 rtw_enusbss=1`
```

This gets really annoying. I'd like it to load at startup by itself. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add a single line:

```
options rtl8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=2 rtw_ips_mode=1 rtw_hwpwrp_detect=1 rtw_enusbss=1
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. You should be all set.